# Setting up batches in tensorflow probability sts

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, tensorflow-probability

I'm having some trouble setting up fitting and forecasting with `tfp.sts`. I'm trying to fit the model to be able to take a sequence of 24 observed timesteps and forecast the following 24 steps. For this, I have taken my large sequence of 365 * 24 values and sliced it into 48-step-long batches (so the observed data matrix has shape `(364, 48)`). I also have another variable for which I am attempting to find linear dependence using `tfp.sts.LinearRegression`, which has the design matrix with shape `(365, 24)`, or `(364, 48, 1)` when converted to batches equivalent to the observed data.

I use variational inference to get parameter samples, and here's where I run into a problem - the samples have shapes `(n_samples, 364)`. I then attempt to perform a forecast using these samples. With that, observed data and design matrix, for forecasts have shapes `(24, )` and `(48, 1)`, respectively (so as if they were one of the batches when training) and I get a memory allocation error because the forecasting function can't allocate space for a tensor with shape `[n_samples,364,24,24]`. This makes me think that I've made a mistake in the batch setup, but I can't see where. I attempted, when creating a surrogate posterior distribution to pass the `batch_size` argument equal to `(364, )`, but this just crashed as well because of a memory allocation error, it attempted to allocate a very large matrix.

Here's some relevant code...

Model function:

```py
def build_model(observed_time_series, features_design):
    hour_of_day_effect = sts.Seasonal(
        num_seasons=24,
        observed_time_series=observed_time_series,
        name='hour_of_day_effect')

    features_effect = sts.LinearRegression(
        design_matrix=features_design,
        name='temperature_effect')

    autoregressive = sts.Autoregressive(
        order=1,
        observed_time_series=observed_time_series,
        name='autoregressive')

    model = sts.Sum([hour_of_day_effect,
                     # day_of_week_effect,
                     # month_of_year_effect,
                     features_effect,
                     autoregressive,
                     # trend
                    ],
                     observed_time_series=observed_time_series)
    return model
```

Training function:

```py
def train_vi(model, observed,
             num_variational_steps=200,
             optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.1),
             nsamples=50):

    variational_posteriors = tfp.sts.build_factored_surrogate_posterior(
        model=model)

    @tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
    def train():
        return tfp.vi.fit_surrogate_posterior(
            target_log_prob_fn=model.joint_log_prob(
                observed_time_series=observed),
            surrogate_posterior=variational_posteriors,
            optimizer=optimizer,
            num_steps=num_variational_steps)
    
    global loss_curve
    loss_curve = train()
    
    return variational_posteriors.sample(nsamples)
```

Forecast function:

```py
def forecast(model, q_samples, observed, steps=24):
    forecast_dist = tfp.sts.forecast(
        model=model,
        observed_time_series=observed,
        parameter_samples=q_samples,
        num_steps_forecast=steps)
    return (forecast_dist.mean().numpy()[..., 0],
            forecast_dist.stddev().numpy()[..., 0])
```

Data setup

```py
train_lim = '2014-01-01'
df_train = df[:train_lim]
df_test = df[train_lim:]

index_start = 0

design_train = []
observed_train = []
for index_end in range(48, len(df_train), 24):
    df_batch = df_train[index_start:index_end]

    design_train.append(df_batch.air_temperature.values.reshape(-1, 1))
    observed_train.append(df_batch[goal])

    index_start += 24

design_train = tf.stack(design_train)
observed_train = np.array(observed_train)
design_train.shape
```

Fitting:

```py
model = build_model(observed_train, design_train)
samples = train_vi(model, observed_train)
```

Forecasting:

```py
day = 15
steps = 24

index_end = day * 24
index_start = index_end - 24

design = df_test.air_temperature[index_start:index_end + steps].values.reshape(-1, 1)
observed = df_test[goal][index_start:index_end].values

model = build_model(observed, design)
means, std = forecast(model, samples, observed, steps=steps) # this fails
```

And this is the stack trace I get:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-cddd6738ba4d> in <module>
     11 
     12 model = build_model(observed, design)
---> 13 means, std = forecast(model, samples, observed, steps=steps)
     14 
     15 plt.plot(range(index_start, index_end + steps), df_test[goal][index_start:index_end + steps], label='actual')

<ipython-input-11-4a8440dedb9e> in forecast(model, q_samples, observed, steps)
      1 def forecast(model, q_samples, observed, steps=24):
----> 2     forecast_dist = tfp.sts.forecast(
      3         model=model,
      4         observed_time_series=observed,
      5         parameter_samples=q_samples,

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/sts/forecast.py in forecast(model, observed_time_series, parameter_samples, num_steps_forecast, include_observation_noise)
    313         num_timesteps=num_observed_steps, param_vals=parameter_samples)
    314     (_, _, _, predictive_means, predictive_covs, _, _
--> 315     ) = observed_data_ssm.forward_filter(observed_time_series, mask=mask)
    316 
    317     # Build a batch of state-space models over the forecast period. Because

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/linear_gaussian_ssm.py in forward_filter(self, x, mask)
    839 
    840     with self._name_and_control_scope('forward_filter', x, {'mask': mask}):
--> 841       return self._forward_filter(x, mask=mask)
    842 
    843   def _forward_filter(self, x, mask=None):

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/linear_gaussian_ssm.py in _forward_filter(self, x, mask)
    923         self.get_observation_noise_for_timestep)
    924 
--> 925     filter_states = tf.scan(update_step_fn,
    926                             elems=x if mask is None else (x, mask),
    927                             initializer=initial_state)

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    572                   func.__module__, arg_name, arg_value, 'in a future version'
    573                   if date is None else ('after %s' % date), instructions)
--> 574       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    575 
    576     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_value_notice_to_docstring(

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py in scan_v2(fn, elems, initializer, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, infer_shape, reverse, name)
    804     ```
    805   """
--> 806   return scan(
    807       fn=fn,
    808       elems=elems,

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py in scan(fn, elems, initializer, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, infer_shape, reverse, name)
    662       initial_i = i
    663       condition = lambda i, _1, _2: i < n
--> 664     _, _, r_a = control_flow_ops.while_loop(
    665         condition,
    666         compute, (initial_i, a_flat, accs_ta),

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations, return_same_structure)
   2733                                               list(loop_vars))
   2734       while cond(*loop_vars):
-> 2735         loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
   2736         if try_to_pack and not isinstance(loop_vars, (list, _basetuple)):
   2737           packed = True

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in <lambda>(i, lv)
   2724         cond = lambda i, lv: (  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
   2725             math_ops.logical_and(i < maximum_iterations, orig_cond(*lv)))
-> 2726         body = lambda i, lv: (i + 1, orig_body(*lv))
   2727       try_to_pack = False
   2728 

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py in compute(i, a_flat, tas)
    645       packed_elems = input_pack([elem_ta.read(i) for elem_ta in elems_ta])
    646       packed_a = output_pack(a_flat)
--> 647       a_out = fn(packed_a, packed_elems)
    648       nest.assert_same_structure(elems if initializer is None else initializer,
    649                                  a_out)

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/linear_gaussian_ssm.py in kalman_filter_step(state, elems_t)
   1596     #  u_{t|t-1} = F_t u_{t-1} + b_t
   1597     #  P_{t|t-1} = F_t P_{t-1} F_t' + Q_t
-> 1598     predicted_mean, predicted_cov = kalman_transition(
   1599         filtered_mean,
   1600         filtered_cov,

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/linear_gaussian_ssm.py in kalman_transition(filtered_mean, filtered_cov, transition_matrix, transition_noise)
   1744                                    transition_matrix,
   1745                                    transition_noise)
-> 1746   predicted_cov = _propagate_cov(filtered_cov,
   1747                                  transition_matrix,
   1748                                  transition_noise)

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/linear_gaussian_ssm.py in _propagate_cov(cov, linop, dist)
   1945   """Propagate covariance through linear Gaussian transformation."""
   1946   # For linop A and input cov P, returns `A P A' + dist.cov()`
-> 1947   return linop.matmul(linop.matmul(cov), adjoint_arg=True) + dist.covariance()

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/linalg/linear_operator_block_diag.py in matmul(self, x, adjoint, adjoint_arg, name)
    341                         else self.domain_dimension)
    342         op_dimension.assert_is_compatible_with(x.shape[arg_dim])
--> 343       return self._matmul(x, adjoint=adjoint, adjoint_arg=adjoint_arg)
    344 
    345   def _matmul(self, x, adjoint=False, adjoint_arg=False):

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/linalg/linear_operator_block_diag.py in _matmul(self, x, adjoint, adjoint_arg)
    369     result_list = linear_operator_util.broadcast_matrix_batch_dims(
    370         result_list)
--> 371     return array_ops.concat(result_list, axis=-2)
    372 
    373   def matvec(self, x, adjoint=False, name="matvec"):

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in concat(values, axis, name)
   1652           dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape().assert_has_rank(0)
   1653       return identity(values[0], name=name)
-> 1654   return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
   1655 
   1656 

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in concat_v2(values, axis, name)
   1205       return _result
   1206     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 1207       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   1208     except _core._FallbackException:
   1209       pass

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6841   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6842   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6843   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6844   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6845 

~/venv/mmes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[50,364,24,24] and type double on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
````